# Do you know what php warning startup unable to load dynamic library http.so is refering?

Tags: php, linux, lamp, redhat

I have Red Hat 5.8 version installed on my server. I have php version 5.3. LAMP works correctly. But when I type " php -v " I see the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
    '/usr/lib/php/modules/http.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/http.so:
    undefined symbol: php_set_error_handling in Unknown on line 0
```

The file `/usr/lib/php/modules/http.so` exists.

And, in php.ini: `extension=http.so`

What is this error referring to?

Comment: Perhaps the `http.so` version is outdated?

Comment: Sounds like the most likely answer is that the CLI binary is a different version than used by the web server, and the CLI version is trying to load a PECL extension compiled for a different version. Create a file with `<?php echo phpversion();` in it, and run it from both the web server and the command line, I suspect you will see different output. In order for this to work, the versions must match, or the two different versions must load there own versions of the extension libraries.

Comment: If anyone stumbles here from google due to a missing `module.so` error like this one on CentOS or similar, it's a [reported issue](https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/issues/254) with an easy fix, edit `/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini` to look for `mcrypt.so` instead.

Comment: My install doesnt have /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini
php version is 5.5 i upgraded by using yum

Answer (score 1):

`http.so` is PECL_HTTP library file. You have syntax error in this library. Try to upgrade your PECL_HTTP extention.

Comment: I tried to upgrade it, but seems there is not necessary upgrade.    yum update PECL_HTTP
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
atomic                                                                                                                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00
atomic/primary_db                                                                                                                                           | 780 kB     00:05
Setting up Update Process
No Match for argument: PECL_HTTP
No package PECL_HTTP available.
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: There is nothing to upgrade, says: # pecl upgrade --> Nothing to upgrade

Comment: ))) You have to define what package do you want to upgrade or pecl tries to upgrade all installed packages. In my case (Centos 5) I use `pecl upgrade pecl_http`. But it seems like you have last versions of all installed packages. I think DaveRandom's comment on your question was more close.

Comment: You are right :)look WARNING channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading pecl_http-1.7.4.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-1.7.4.tgz
Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings ..Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. .... 71 source files,building
running: phpize Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626  1. whether to enable cURL HTTP requests; specify libcurl directory : yes

Comment: `Warning: strtotime()` - set `date.timezone` in php.ini according to your timezone. Others are depend on your curl lib location.